# Как написать запрос SELECT ... INNER JOIN на codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, join, inner

```
SELECT 
   messages.*, users.name, users.surname,users.image
FROM messages 
INNER JOIN users ON(from_id= users.id)
WHERE 
   (from_id = $_SESSION[id] AND to_id = $all_id) OR 
   (from_id = $all_id AND to_id=$_SESSION[id]);
```

---

```
public function getMessages($all_id){
    return $this->db->select("SELECT messages.*, users.name, users.surname,users.image
      FROM messages INNER JOIN users ON(from_id= users.id)
    WHERE (from_id = $_SESSION[id] AND to_id = $all_id)
    OR (from_id = $all_id AND to_id=$_SESSION[id])");
 }
```

Comment: **[Как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Comment: какая у Вас версия CI ?

Comment: CodeIgniter 3  ,,,,

Comment: код оформляйте в виде кода - на панели инструментов есть фигурные скобки

Comment: `$_SESSION[id]` - `id` должно быть в кавычках

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821687/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('messages.*, users.name, users.surname,users.image');
$this->db->from('messages');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = messages.from_id','inner');
$where = "(messages.from_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND messages.to_id = '$all_id') OR 
   (messages.from_id = '$all_id' AND messages.to_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."')";
$this->db->where($where);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

[Документация](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное)

Comment: пожалуйста. не стесняйтесь изучать документацию, она очень хорошо расписана,  если уже не будет получаться приходите еще)